# Unable to build or run tests in Intellij for Java project

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I am new to Java and checked-out a project from Git. After setting project in IntelliJ. I am getting below errors

```
Error:(4, 19) java: package core does not exist
Error:(5, 35) java: package org.openqa.selenium.logging does not exist
Error:(6, 1) java: package org.testng does not exist
Error:(7, 17) java: package core.util does not exist
Error:(8, 31) java: package core.webdriver.template does not exist
Error:(16, 40) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol: class BaseUtil
Error:(16, 60) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol: class ITestListener
```

Any idea what am I missing ?

Note: 1) I have installed Java 1.8 and set the environment path (i.e. jdk bin path)
      2) I have set the compiler as javac in IntelliJ config
      3) I am able to run 'java -version' and see the version of java installed (from command line
      4) When i hit 'javac' in command line. It says "javac is not recognized as internal or external command,operable program or batch file.

Please help

Comment: What did you get with the command `java -version` in the console?

Comment: Is it an open source project ? Please add reference to it, so that we can further assist.

Comment: Also check that sources folder are correctly set: In Project Structure > Modules > Sources, check that source folders are correctly set. For a maven project, this is typically `src/main/java`.

Answer (score 1):

Does the project have a build file to it? I'd search for a build.gradle or a pom.xml file.
You should install the build system needed for the project, and then you can build it.